# How can I get to any place in the file system in the graphical folder display?

Tags: 18.04, filesystem

This is a question so basic that it must be answered somewhere, probably somewhere obvious, but I have searched everywhere I can think of, both on the computer and online (e.g. help.ubuntu.com, askubuntu.com, Google, etc etc) and I can't find it anywhere.

I have recently switched from Ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04. In the file system graphical interface I can easily get to /home/myname and all its subfolders, such as my "Documents" folder and so on, but I can't find how to go to other parts of the filing system. In 16.04 if I wanted to get a display of, for example, / or /home or /dev or anywhere else I could get there by selecting "go" in the file menu and typing or pasting in the path to the place I wanted, but 18.04 does not have that menu item. How can I do it?

Comment: There should probably be a button/link called "Computer" in the left sidebar of your Nautilus file manager, which takes you to the `/` folder.

Comment: @ByteCommander on 17.10 and onward this link is gone, and you can only find it under other locations

Comment: Thanks. It's actually "Other locations" then "Computer", but I got there. So obvious, but I didn't find it. However, I'm afraid it still isn't the complete answer to my problem, because I want to get to ~/.cache and I can't navigate to there from / . Can anyone help me get there?

Comment: Press ctrl+h to show/hide hidden files. (i.e. dot files)

Comment: Thanks, Videonauth. I had in fact found how to get there myself, and came back here to say so, but thanks even so, because I didn't know that ctrl+h was a shortcut for that.

Comment: @ByteCommander do you want to write the answer, since you commented first?  :)

Comment: @Videonauth Nah, my guess didn't match anyway. Take it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default file manager Nautilus supports Ctrl+L shortcut. That'll highlight the address bar, and you can type in destination you want, whether it's `/` or `/usr` or anything else. Hit enter to actually navigate there.

You can also type special destinations such as `trash:///`. Notice the tripple slash.

Note that `~` is property of command-line utilities ( aka shell ) and may not work in graphical file managers.

Comment: `/usr` I think you meant?

Comment: Yes thank you. I apparently can't type without typos today

Comment: Thanks, Sergiy Kolodyazhnyy. Ctrl+L gives me exactly what I was looking for, though I now also know other ways of getting there that I didn't know before.